# Typescript Factory class that avoids using a switch statement when using enum as an input?

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums, switch-statement, factory-pattern

```
abstract class Animal {
    abstract sound(): void;
}

class Cat extends Animal {
    sound(){
        console.log("meow");
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    sound(){
        console.log("bark");
    }
}

enum AnimalType {
  Cat = 1,
  Dog = 2,
}

class AnimalFactory {
  static createAnimal(type: AnimalType): Animal {
    switch (type) {
      case AnimalType.Cat:
        return new Cat();
      case AnimalType.Dog:
        return new Dog();
      default:
        throw new Error("unsupported animal type");
    }
  }
}

const cat = AnimalFactory.createAnimal(AnimalType.Cat);
const dog = AnimalFactory.createAnimal(AnimalType.Dog);
cat.sound();
dog.sound();
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgggOwJYFthkEBvAKAUoVEhngTAHsBXbAEwAoBKALgQDdGuNgG4yAXzJkUaDAGFgiAKYAPCEvYYcBIqQpUmrTl3JUzSRtibIlAOmSMA5hwBE+JYwDuLrmLOTJaVR0BAARJwRVdU0sPEJiUwMWdm5E8wsrRht7J1cQYCgAax8-KgCpDWZ8WJ1kABUATwAHJT1KBUQAXgQARgAafXDHBG6AJgHAmRDteIAxOAhGKAa2hghFXFgkKCVFJRmiDghmpT4D+pPeGvjVyjBPXAhYAAsEI8vbqlg0VvPGltsHR4+nSOwgzCg2AQ2CUngQHW4pTM3zAvziRH+diGwPSlDBEKhMLhQ0RIKobCUADNgMxkBAcbiIM8oF5obCEABRKAsqCuVhgZhNJpLdRsajo4jHFolMmSSjlaSWSBIRQja5EebwJYNWywHZ7c4cP4nQGKXyKqyINgRbrnTWLZa6-XqQ3GgFDc3fCC2Qwpc3Wxw+5LGERAA)

I'm trying to get better at the [Open–closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle) and I'm trying to figure out how to avoid using switch statements and decouple the factory class with the enum when I add more subclasses of Animal. The user via an API is sending over what animal is to be created via a simple enum. Is it possible to modify the AnimalFactory in a way that I don't need to modify the factory class every time I add another enum value and subclass of Animal?

Am I going at this wrong and I need more than an enum to use as an argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a constant that contains a mapping of `enum` values to class types, and use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to create a type mapping:

```
abstract class Animal {
    abstract sound(): void;
}

class Cat extends Animal {
    sound() {
        console.log("meow");
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    sound() {
        console.log("bark");
    }
}

enum AnimalType {
  Cat = 1,
  Dog = 2,
}

const animals = {
     [AnimalType.Cat]: Cat,
     [AnimalType.Dog]: Dog
};

type Animals = {
     [A in keyof typeof animals]: InstanceType<typeof animals[A]>
};

class AnimalFactory {
  static createAnimal<A extends keyof Animals>(type: A): Animals[A] {
    return new animals[type]();
  }
}

const cat = AnimalFactory.createAnimal(AnimalType.Cat);
const dog = AnimalFactory.createAnimal(AnimalType.Dog);
cat.sound();
dog.sound();
```

---

See it on the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=40&ssc=13&pln=1&pc=1#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgggOwJYFthkEBvAKAUoVEhngTAHsBXbAEwAoBKALgQDdGuNgG4yAXzJkUaDAGFgiAKYAPCEvYYcBIqQpUmrTlz1UzSRtibIlAOmSMA5hwBE+JYwDuLrmLOTJaVR0BAARJwRVdU0sPEJicjNDdm5Tc0pYS2s7B2cXEGAoAGsfPyoAqQ1mfFidZAAVAE8AByU0hUQAXgQARgAafXDHBG6AJgHAzKtEYDiiDG7EswBtbXim1tsOgF0+DoHzVbmGlrsh3bCnCTEyCFPa+IW0qlWEXGwEIqVGxgAzBDurT+1GOYAuAElprNYEoNkoADyAjz-WZ1MCrbYAPmuUhkITWRAAYnAIIwoI00pBFLhYEgoEpFEoCch4ZhImoNGwMF8fv9mWBMRwkXxMLwHvMMc8EPSIMwoB9sEpPCC0cskdtuGUKtIsohYIoRuLkMT4GTGrZYPTGcyOMy4VtFL4ddMEGwIt1mSbSeSLVb1Da7adbEMnfqILZksYxG7HBGWCknUA)